# Assigning Maya render settings manually from json data

Tags: python, arrays, json, maya

I want to apply a dictionary of key/value data from a json file into Maya's render settings.

Currently, I have a dictionary of 16 items formatted as follows:

```
{u'defaultRenderGlobals.blurSharpness': 1.0, u'defaultRenderGlobals.enableDefaultLight': False}
```

I can now convert to a list, however I am unsure how exactly I should loop through the data and assign it to the correct attributes inside Mata using cmds.setAttr() command.

Could anyone suggest a good method to assign? I am aware that Maya has it's own function to load a full render setup json, but here I am looking for a way so assign only certain arrays as required.

Thank you,

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Maya, so I can't test this, but it sounds like you want something like

```
for k, v in settings.items():
    cmds.setAttr(k, v)
```

where `settings` is your 16-item dictionary of settings.

Comment: Hi Kodiologist, yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CKane In that case, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: sure thing, done